# Django Reverse Match when using AJAX

Tags: python, django, ajax

I am having difficulties in getting my reverse match to work. I am using Django and Ajax to make an asynchronous entry/update in the database.

My URLs looks like this:

```
path('overview/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/$', overview_view, name='overview'),
```

My view:

```
def overview_view(request, year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().month, day=datetime.now().day):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        office_id = request.POST.get('office_id')
       
        print(office_id)

        return render(request, 'overview/overview.html', context)
```

obviously, this is a work in progress and just so empty to test it :)

My AJAX call looks like this:

```
        var csrf = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
        $('#location-select1').on('change', function () {
            var location_selection = this.value;
            console.log(location_selection)


            $.ajax({
                url: '',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    office_id: location_selection, // TODO adjust with office that is selected
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf
                },
            });
        });
        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            window.location.reload();
        });
```

My Error message from Django Debugger looks like this:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'overview' with keyword arguments '{'year': '', 'month': '', 'day': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['overview/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/(?P<day>[0-9]+)/\\$$', 'overview/$']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!!

UPDATE:
I have just added `return reverse('overview', kwargs={'year': context['day1'].year, 'month': context['day1'].month, 'day': context['day1'].day})`to the bottom of my view.However, now I am getting those errors

```
Internal Server Error: /overview/2021/4/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/manueloliverburi/Google_Drive/4_Code/Floq_Django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "Floq_Django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "Floq_Django/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Why is that?

Comment: share your view please

Comment: You don't say, but I assume your server is responding to your AJAX request with a 500 Internal Server Error. Where is the python code making the reverse() call?

Comment: @SerioUs I updated the question

Comment: @GregBall I updated the question including the view

Comment: @manfrefobelugo post request and 3 parameters? the hole point of the post request its because it don't pass the parameters in the url path!

Comment: I know @SerioUs... I am using those parameters for the get request that is why those are there ....

Comment: Are you importing `render` from `django.shortcuts`? Your view code seems to be returning a str. Oops, sorry, now I've read your update propery. reverse() is returning a string; why are you calling reverse() at all?

Comment: @GregBall so if I call reverse, then the ajax call seems to be successful, however, I am getting the errors above... maybe you are able to help me find the cause?

Comment: Your URL waits for data in the URL itself. Something like `http://your.domain/2021/3/24`, but you are passing the data over a POST call as '{'year': '', 'month': '', 'day': ''}'. In other words, empty values...

Comment: @PauloMarques thanks a lot for your comment. I mean the ajax call is successful, however, I get those error messages...

Comment: A view must return an instance of HttpResponse. You're returning a string, causing an exception to be thrown (the one you give the traceback for), which is then converted into a 500 Internal Server Error response sent to the browser. Unclear how you define "successful" for your AJAX request, do you mean it doesn't throw a JS exception? Also unclear why you are trying to return a URL.